# landscape generator in ubuntu

Tags: 21.04, 3d

I want to install a landscape generator, I looked:

1. Instant Terra
2. VUE
3. Terragen
4. World Creator
5. World Machine
6. Gaea

and noticed that they all work in Windows.

I found a FlowScape (more a toy) and picogen (a fairly old generator), they seemed to me not quite suitable.

**Are there modern terrain generators in Ubuntu ??**

Comment: Some suggestion [here](https://www.goodfirms.co/blog/the-7-best-free-and-open-source-landscape-design-software)

Answer (score 3):

Blender is the way, at the moment. This software evolved a lot during the last years, and there are plugins for a lot of things. It also has a huge potential to do a lot of things procedurally (algorithms), even with Python.

Take a look at this tutorial, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrMee2gcS20

Check this addon called ANT, for Blender: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/ant_landscape.html

And check this addon called Dynamic Sky, for Blender: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/lighting/dynamic_sky.html

I'm a big fan of Terragen, I used Vue and Mojoworld as well.